# Garden building (UK) 2.5m rule where measured?

Tags: uk, planning, building

Please see the image below. I have dug down 250mm from both fences.

In order to comply with the 2.5m height limit for a flat roof structure within 2m of a boundary.

**Question:** Is that 2.5m measured from the immediate boundary or the actual building itself?

I would prefer to have the building 2.75m in height.

[image]

Comment: Check with the UK planning authorities - we don’t keep copies of the regulations for every country.

Comment: The online documentation is not clear, hoping someone could clarify

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. If an answer is helpful, please click the large check mark next to it to accept. And, please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know the details of contributing here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the info in your question;

- If the structure is within 2m of the boundary then the height  of that structure is restricted to 2.5m.

That would mean that if your structure is within the 2m of the boundary then **you can not have a structure  that is 2.75m in height**   as it would violate the code.

> Is that 2.5m measured from the immediate boundary or the actual
> building itself?

The 2.5m height restriction is measured from grade (*the ground*), to the the top of the structure. *Grade would be the ground at the bottom of the fence, not from the bottom of the hole you dug.* Dig the hole deeper.

***Again, this is based on how your question is worded.***